# matrix exponentiation in linear recursion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, matrix

I am trying to do http://www.spoj.com/problems/FIBTWIST/ problem by linear recursion. However, since the constraints are large I have to use matrix exponentiation.
I have read http://zobayer.blogspot.in/2010/11/matrix-exponentiation.html
so according to it equations formed are

```
ft(n)=ft(n-1)+ft(n-2)+g(n)    ft(0)=0, ft(0)=1
g(n) =g(n-1)+1                g(1)=0
```

But now I am confused how to form matrices A and B of the form A*M=B. It is given as Type 7 in mentioned blogspot link but I am having difficulty in understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a third sequence, fut, Fibonacci-untwist, as

> fut(n)=ft(n)+(n+2).

Then

> fut(n)=ft(n)+n+1=ft(n-1)+ft(n-2)+(n-1)+(n+2)=fut(n-2)+fut(n-1)

So fut is just another solution of the Fibonacci recursion, and thus

> fut(n)=f(n-1)*fut(0)+f(n)*fut(1)=2*f(n-1)+4*f(n)=2*f(n)+2*f(n+1)=2*f(n+2)

and finally

> ft(n)=2*f(n+2)-(n+2)

Test:

```
    f(n):   0  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34
2*f(n+2):   2  4  6 10 16 26 42 68
     n+2:   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
   ft(n):   0  1  2  5 10 19 34 59
```

and really, the last row is the difference of the second and third row.

Comment: I am not able to understand how did you got this equation fut(n)=f(n-1)*fut(0)+f(n)*fut(1) . And shouldn't be fut(n)=ft(n)+n+1.

Comment: f(n-1) and f(n) form the basis of the solution space of the Fibonacci recursion. And no, the constant is correct this way.

Comment: I am still not getting the part of f(n-1) and f(n-2) .